# Duplicate parent objects returned after the @OneToMany is used

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate

I have three tables: A, B, C - in terms of entities, A is the parent entity and contains lists of B and C.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
public class A implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<B> bSet;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<C> cSet;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="B")
public class B implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private A a;

    //other fields...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="C")
public class C implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private A a;

   //other fields...

}
```

They all are fetched from the database with this approcach:

```
 @Override
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "AJpaRepository.findAll", cacheManager = "mysqlCacheManager")
    @Query(value = "FROM A a"
        + " LEFT JOIN FETCH a.bSet"
        + " LEFT JOIN FETCH a.cSet")
    List<A> findAll();
```

The thing I wanted to get when use findAll():

```
A : {id =1, bSet=[...], cSet=[...]}
A : {id =2, bSet=[...], cSet=[...]}
A : {id =3, bSet=[...], cSet=[...]}
A : {id =4, bSet=[...], cSet=[...]} 
...
```

The thing I'm actually getting:

```
A : {id =1, bSet=[...], cSet=[...]}
A : {id =1, bSet=[...], cSet=[...]}
A : {id =1, bSet=[...], cSet=[...]}
A : {id =2, bSet=[...], cSet=[...]} 
...
```

There are duplicated A objects with absolutely equal content (including bSet and cSet). Is there a way to handle it somehow gracefully at hibernate level instead of using Set or distinct on a higher processing level?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turn out pretty simple, just added distinct to a query, but still if anyone has more "hibernate like" solution pls add here

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT a FROM A a"
        + " LEFT JOIN FETCH a.bSet"
        + " LEFT JOIN FETCH a.cSet")
```